# Banding in baked image texture

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, file-format

So I baked my image textures in 32bit float and exported 16bit PNG. And I'm getting banding when I apply those textures to the model... When I preview the images, it doesn't appear to have banding, but when I apply them to the model, there they are...

Is it as simple as exporting/saving in a higher bit depth (32 Bit Float) w/ a different file type other than PNG (if so, which file type is best for exporting)?

Previewing the PNG photo:
[image]

Applied to model:
[image]

Comment: Hi :). Looks kinda like a ['moiré pattern'](https://photographylife.com/what-is-moire) - caused by too high detail in too low resolution. Not sure how to solve it though :))

Comment: If you asking for a file type for 32-bit I prefer go with .exr, blender has that in export type. Also the banding might be cuz of what Jachym Explained above, Try to do a quick cycles image render and see if u can see the banding in render, cuz render and viewport are different, so It will be easier to know if the error is cuz of Viewport's graphics, or something else.

Comment: Hi, yes, I did a quick test render and there is the Moire  pattern... But something interesting is that the pattern is only showing in the NORMAL MAP... (maybe that's what yall were trying to say, but I didn't catch it..) But the EXR format did help with the other maps... Any tips for the Normal Map though?